# how to use google cloud to launch a Apache web server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to Running a basic Apache web server on google cloud (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/basic-webserver-apache)

But I can't connect with my  External IP .

Last month I succeed launching a server with the External IP, why can't this time?

I have  Allow HTTP Traffic box.

How to find the bug?

Answer (score 1):

Restart the VM then check out if the Firewall-rules still activated:

`$ gcloud compute firewall-rules list | grep 80`

if not is created the firewall-rule, set it up again:

```
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-http --allow tcp:80
```

hope it can be useful to you

Comment: your welcome, I got the same issue at my first time :)